# An AWS KMS policy to limit access by the key creator role

Tags: amazon-kms

What would be an example of AWS KMS policy that will not allow any other principal to access the key except the role that has been used to create it? In addition, would such a policy be accepted by AWS if submitted programmatically, rather than through KMS console?

The approach described below has been unsuccessful.

Through the AWS console in account 444444444444, I can create a KMS key with a policy (see below).

KMSCreateCustomerKeyRole in account 444444444444 is a cross-account role for account 3333333333333. In the latter there is encryption_key_manager user in a user group that can assume KMSCreateCustomerKeyRole.

Logging into AWS console as a encryption_key_manager user and assuming KMSCreateCustomerKeyRole, a key with the same policy also gets created successfully.

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "key-default-1",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Enable IAM User Permissions",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::444444444444:root"
        },
        "Action": "kms: *",
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "Deny for everyone except the specified role and user",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "NotPrincipal": {
            "AWS": [
                "arn:aws:iam::444444444444:root",
                "arn:aws:sts::444444444444:assumed-role/KMSCreateCustomerKeyRole/ encryption_key_manager",
                "arn:aws:iam::444444444444:role/KMSCreateCustomerKeyRole"
            ]
        },
        "Action": "kms: *",
        "Resource": "*"
    }
]
}
```

So far, it works in the sense that other users/role can't access the key through the console.

However, key creation should be done programmatically, so to test this policy I try to create a key via cli. CLI uses the KMSCreateCustomerKeyRole profile, which points to the default encryption_key_manager profile with aws credentials file as

```
[default] 
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::444444444444:role/KMSCreateCustomerKeyRole source_profile = encryption_key_manager

[encryption_key_manager]  
aws_access_key_id = .....
```

get-caller-identity returns

```
{
"UserId": "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA:botocore-session-1640070193",
"Account": "444444444444",
"Arn": "arn:aws:sts::444444444444: assumed-role/KMSCreateCustomerKeyRole/botocore-session-1640070193"
}
```

Key generation request

```
 aws kms create-key --description another_key --policy file: //policy.json --region us-east-2
```

results in an error occurred (MalformedPolicyDocumentException) when calling the CreateKey operation: The new key policy will not allow you to update the key policy in the future.

Same error is produced for encryption_key_manager profile

```
 aws kms create-key --description another_key --policy file: //policy.json --profile encryption_key_manager --region us-east-2
```

I thought that this may happen because while using command line we pass to AMS KMS an ARN with session-id, and KMS can't match this ARN to any of ARN in the array for NotPrincipal in Deny part of the policy. I have added the ARN with session id     (arn:aws:sts::444444444444: assumed-role/ KMSCreateCustomerKeyRole/botocore-session-1640070193) to the ARN's array, but the error stays the same.

Comment: I do think such a policy exists. What makes you think it does?

Comment: Hi @luk2302, thanks for the comment. I haven't found any AWS document  mentioning that there couldn't be such a policy. Would appreciate a link, if you aware of any.

Comment: Such a document obviously does not exist. There are lots of things you cannot do even though it's not stated anywhere that it is impossible. Read the entire IAM reference on conditions and condition keys and KMS key policies and then you know what is possible - everything else is impossible.

Comment: @luk2302, then should your first comment be read as "I don't thnk ..." ?

Comment: Facepalm, thank you autocorrect... yes, i don't think it exists. The things you can do with conditions is quite limited. And generally AWS does not have a concept of resource ownership / creators

Comment: Right, I didn't find a condition that would limit access by role. On the other hand, this example uses Principal and NotPrincipal  https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-kms-workshop/blob/master/Section-3-Working-with-Web-App.md#least-privilege---access-only-from-a-role . However, I am getting "The new key policy will not allow you to update the key policy in the future. (Service: AWSKMS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: MalformedPolicyDocumentException" on trying to use it programmatically.

Comment: Yes, you can obviously restrict the access to specific roles but not "the creator" because the creator is not tracked. What role are you using to create the key and what policy are you trying to set.

Comment: @luk2302,  let's get rid of the notion of creator and reformulate the problem as following. The role that a user/program assumes to create a KMS key is specified in the key's policy as the only role which being assumed may access the key in the future.
If such policy is possible, then what it is? If not, then what specific feature of KMS doesn't allow it? Thanks!

Comment: Did you use exactly the policy mentioned in your link and just replaced the role name and account id? Or did you change anything else about it?

Comment: @luk2302, I put details on how I have changed the tutorial's example into the description of the problem.